# django 1.5.12 upgrade timeout

Tags: django, performance, csv, django-1.5

I am running some tests on django 1.5.12 and am having timeout issues with a feature that works in earlier versions of django. I am basically looping through 3000 records and output using csv.writerow.

My problem does not seem to be related to the csv output specifically but the combination of the number of records and the output to csv, a smaller subset works fine.

I have looked through the release notes and cannot see anything obvious that could be causing this.

I have tried switching to streaming StreamingHttpResponse but still have the same problem.

Any ideas gratefully received.
Thanks
Mathew

Comment: what about simply using print statements to the console if its just a test?

Comment: I have switched to print as suggested. It prints all the rows and then timesout when returning the empty csv?

Again if i reduce the numbers from 3000 to 100 for example then the empty csv is returned.

Comment: After further tests of a working virtualenv against non working this problem does not lie with the django version (or gunicorn) but must be with one of the other required packages. Not sure yet which.